# Will Villagers maintain their Profession from 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I recently updated to 1.14, and returned to one of the villages that I had previously visited. For the most part, all the villagers did not have any professions (when I clicked on them they simply waggled their heads at me). However, there were two Librarians in the village.

These were the only two Villagers I had traded with, pre-1.14. They had their pre-existing trades, though obviously in the new format.

Is this the case for this situation? Or is it just my luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do the same in a creative world. First off, I spawned 8 villagers. I tried trading with 5 of the 8 villagers, and I didn't interact with the other 3 at all.

When I launched the world in 1.14, the first thing I noticed was that the 3 villagers I did not interact with had no professions (comparison picture: villagers I traded with on the left, villagers I didn't trade with on the right)

[image: Comparison.]

Next, I checked if the offers were all the same, and indeed, they were. Each villager had the same 4 or 5 offers as before. Here are examples:

[image: Comparison.]

[image: Comparison.]

As you can see, the trades remain, just like in your world.

The villagers I did not interact with acted the same way as yours: I could not trade with them in any way.

As a conclusion it is safe to say that your world is no exception. Villagers that had offers in earlier versions will keep them into 1.14, and villagers with no data will become pointless annoying nitwits.

Comment: Nitwit bullying! :(

Comment: So you mean that [this bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-148923) doesn't happen in 1.14.0? Interesting, it's confirmed for the last prerelease and usually there aren't any major changes between last prerelease and release.

Comment: @FabianRöling Seems like the bug doesn't affect old villagers anymore, or at least the ones with which the player already traded with. It's not something bad if you ask me though :)