# Are pre-existing Villagers affected by workstations?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After asking [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350517/will-villagers-maintain-their-profession-from-1-13), Villagers from 1.13 that you have traded with, then upgraded to 1.14 will maintain their Profession and trades in 1.14. Any that you have *not* traded with, will lose theirs, and can be assigned new ones at will.

However, can these pre-existing "Professional" Villagers be affected by workstations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this, and yes, they are affected by workstations. I tried several different types and they all gave the villager the appropriate profession.

Comment: And did it delete the old trades?

Comment: @FabianRöling the ones I interacted with before switching to 1.14 kept their trades, the ones I didn't interact with lost their professions and their trades.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you understand by 'affected'.

Any villager you haven't traded with previously will become unemployed (losing current profession) directly after update - and then promptly find any unoccupied workstation and obtain a matching profession. (obvious exception: nitwits. Nitwits will be nitwits forever.)

Villagers you have traded with will keep their trades, even without workstations, or in presence of mismatching workstations. They still need their respective workstation type to reset most of their trades once you lock them through trading (currently (1.13.2-pre3) there's a bug that makes some pre-existing trades never to lock up)  - but they won't change their professions normally. They will also be affected by their new workstations in that they will pathfind to them twice a day during 'work hours'.

Additionally, [Rays Works found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5rcOC2FuU0) that through a very specific upgrade path you can earn your pre-existing "professionals" new 1.14-specific trades on top of the pre-existing ones through the new workstation. Details in the linked video.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) however my question is about villagers with *existing* professions.

Comment: @Ben: All villagers before 1.14 have existing traders, except nitwits. By default, two per villager.

Comment: The question I linked covers this - when you update from 1.13 to 1.14, all villagers that you *have* previously traded with will maintain their previous professions. Those that you did not trade with, will lose them.

Comment: @Ben: Ok, edited...